# Diferença entre SHA-1 de debug e produção

Tags: flutter

Comecei a estudar sobre o framework Flutter e gostaria de saber qual é a diferença entre SHA-1 de *DEBUG* e *RELEASE* (Produção), pois lendo a documentação disponibilizada pelo Flutter, salvo algum mal entendido, o comando especificado para *debug* e *release* produzem o mesmo resultado (mesmo código SHA-1).

Existe alguma diferença entre a SHA-1 de *DEBUG* e *RELEASE*? Se sim, Qual seria essa diferença?

Comment: Importante você `EDITAR` esta pergunta, explicando-a de forma clara, objetiva e direta, enfatizando a dificuldade encontrada. Além disso, nos forneça um [Exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) do problema, junto com sua tentativa de resolução. E mais, sugiro a leitura do [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%C3%AAncia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs) para entender melhor o funcionamento da plataforma e não ter maiores frustrações.

Comment: Renato, a chave SHA-1 (Debbug | produção) não é algo "feito" pelo Flutter, isso é relacionado ao Android e o Gradle. Provavelmente você viu uma forma de geração de chave que muitos ensinam que gera algumas chaves para DEBUG para simular _debug, release, debugTest, DebugAndroidTest_ tudo dentro do ambiente de DEBUG, então gera a chave igual em ambos. A chave para ambiente _RELEASE_ pode conter dados da empresa, cidade, etc... É uma "assinatura" que será utilizada pelo Google para saber identificar sua aplicação em alguns serviços.

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro podia pegar uma referência, adicionar um pouco mais de informação e publicar uma resposta, seria boa :)

Comment: @RafaelTavares eu estava sem tempo de elaborar algo, já providenciei uma resposta, espero ter conseguido explicar corretamente.

Answer (score 3):

### Resumidamente

---

SHA-1 não é uma coisa "feita" pelo Flutter, mas sim algo que o Android utiliza.

A assinatura SHA-1 DEBUG é certificado de assinatura mais "basica" utilizada para funcionar algumas coisas enquanto você desenvolve sua aplicação, como o próprio nome diz, em modo DEBUG.

> Quando você gera um APK para testes, o mesmo é assinado com uma chave SHA-1.

A assinatura SHA-1 RELEASE é um certificado de assinatura que possuí "mais dados" que o Google irá utilizar para identificar sua aplicação.
Você tem acesso a ela após gerar uma *key.keysotre* utilizando o `keytool` que é disponibilizado pelo Java;

> **Para gerar a keystore, alguns dados são requisitados:**
>
> • Seu nome
>
> • Nome da empresa
>
> • Cidade e Estado onde você ou sua empresa reside

Você diz que "*o comando especificado para debug e produção produzem o mesmo resultado (mesmo código SHA)*"

Provavelmente deve ter utilizado a task do gradle chamada "signingReport" que gera uma assinatura SHA-1 igual para todas as suas variantes de projeto (Flavors), que por padrão o Flutter traz configurado apenas os de DEBUG.

### O que é SHA-1?

---

É uma criptografia que é utilizada, no contexto da pergunta, como uma chave para sua aplicação.
Ela serve como uma "Impressão de chave de assinatura" ou "Certificado de assinatura", para que o google permita o uso de algumas APIs para seu dispositivo;

Você pode ler um pouco mais sobre aqui [SHA-1 Key – Android](https://brunonotes.wordpress.com/2017/12/22/sha-1-key-android/#:%7E:text=O%20SHA-1%20%C3%A9%20um,chamada%20de%20digesto%20da%20mensagem.).

> Certain Google Play services (such as Google Sign-in and App Invites)
> require you to provide the SHA-1 of your signing certificate so we can
> create an OAuth2 client and API key for your app. To get your SHA-1,
> follow the instructions to use Keytool or Gradle's Signing Report.
>
> *Fonte: [Autenticando seu "Cliente"](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth)*

Um exemplo de serviço que utiliza a SHA-1 é o Firebase, que quando você está desenvolvendo sua aplicação pode ou não informar a SHA-1 ao incluir o aplicativo no Firebase; Mas caso não informe, algumas coisas não irão funcionar, pois é necessária, como por exemplo, para  o Dynamic Links, para o Invites e para o Login do Google ou para receber suporte por telefone no Auth.

### Qual a diferença entre os tipos assinatura SHA-1

---

#### DEBUG

Em alguns lugares você pode encontrar ensinando a utilizar uma task do *gradle* chamada [signingReport](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth#using_gradles_signing_report).

O `signingReport` cria uma chave de assinatura para todas as variantes (Flavors) do ambiente DEBUG, que é o que vem por padrão em sua aplicação Flutter.

Você pode ver isso no seu gradle a nivel do app: seu_projeto\android\app\build.gradle

> ```
> buildTypes {
>     release {
>         // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
>         // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
>         signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
>     }
> }
> ```

Ao rodar o comando através do CMD:

> seu_projeto\android\gradlew signingReport

Serão geradas as chaves de assinatura de DEBUG para sua aplicação, sendo todas iguais, pois nesse momento "não interessa muito"...

[image: Exemplo chaves iguais]

#### RELEASE

Agora sim essa assinatura interessa, é com ela que o Google irá validar várias coisas e identificar seu aplicativo.

Para gerar ela, você precisa seguir alguns passos diferentes, utilizando o `keytool` que é uma ferramenta que vem junto com o `Java`.

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin\keytool.exe
>
> *(Poder ver aqui: [Flutter - Assinando o app -
> EN](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#signing-the-app))*

Através de um comando, você irá criar uma *keystore* que é um arquivo criptografado que você precisará para assinar seu aplicativo em RELEASE.

> keytool -genkey -v -keystore C:\Users\MATHEUS\keyteste\key.jks
> -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key

> **Ao executar o comando, você terá que responder algumas perguntas para gerar sua chave**
>
> ```
> Enter keystore password:
> Re-enter new password:
> What is your first and last name?
>   [Unknown]:  Matheus Miranda
> What is the name of your organizational unit?
>   [Unknown]:  Matheus S/A
> What is the name of your organization?
>   [Unknown]:  Matheus Ltda
> What is the name of your City or Locality?
>   [Unknown]:  Bauru
> What is the name of your State or Province?
>   [Unknown]:  São Paulo
> What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
>   [Unknown]:  SP
> Is CN=Matheus Miranda, OU=Matheus S/A, O=Matheus Ltda, L=Bauru, ST=SÆo Paulo, C=SP correct?
>   [no]:
> ```

Com esse arquivo gerado, você pode utilizar um outro comando que irá lhe fornecer a assinatura SHA-1.

> keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\MATHEUS\keyteste\key.jks -alias
> key

Após gerar esse arquivo, você utiliza o mesmo para configurar corretamente o build type RELEASE para enviar para a loja. *~~Não irei me aprofundar*

> Espero ter conseguido explicar, e caso eu tenha dito alguma besteira
> ou citado informações incorretas, por favor apontem o problema.

Comment: `SHA-1` não é do `Android`.

Comment: @Sorack eu sei que não é do _Android_, tanto que no começo da resposta eu cito que não é algo do Flutter mas sim algo que o Android **utiliza** (E não digo que é "dele"). Existe algo que posso melhorar em minha resposta? Posso não ter deixado muito claro

Comment: Não, acho que a sua resposta está "OK"